# Clarity on response formats and page reload for html response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to understand the response `format` actions in Rails. Suppose I have a `link_to` in my partial which is rendered in `show` page like below:

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'my_partial', locals: { stage: @stage } %>
```

**my_partial.html.erb**

```
<% case 'stage' %>
<% when 'beginning' %>
  <%= link_to 'Submit', { controller: 'my_controller', action: 'update_model' } %>
<% when 'ongoing' %>
  <%= render partial: 'another_partial' %>
<% end %>
```

**my_controller.rb**

```
def update_model
  #do something
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { some_key: some_value } }
    format.js { render partial: 'path_to_partial/partial.js' }
    format.html { redirect_to action: 'show' }
  end
end
```

Here whenever `show` page is loaded for the first time `@stage` will be `beginning` and then on clicking `link_to 'Submit'` then before the response from controller the `@stage` will be changed to `ongoing`.

Now Whenever I click on `link_to`, the page reloads and the `response` is in `html` so `format.html` is sent. If I add `remote: true` then the response is in `js` and the page does not reload because it is `remote`.

So the exact functionality that I want is to re render the `show` page and then inside the `my_partial` it should go to `when ongoing` and then render the `another_partial` page without reloading. This happens in the same url.

What I am trying to understand is why does the page reload when it is the same url? Is that how `format.html` works? What should I do to render the `show` page again but without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

What the `respond_to do |format|` does it looks which response the incoming http request is expecting.
Normally, if you click on a link or submit a form, it expects html. But, as you state correctly, if you add `remote: true` the http request issued by the link is expecting javascript. 
Now you want to rerender only the partial, not the whole page. You can do it like so
in the controller

```
def update_model
 ...
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
    format.js 
    ...
  end
end
```

Don't give a block to `format.js` this will automatically render a file in the views which - like always - should be named like the controller action.
So `update_model.js.erb`
And here you can decide what to do.
So for example find the div that holds your partial and then rerender it. Thanks to `.erb` you can write embedded ruby code in this js file too. And this is where you decide which part to rerender or whatever to do (toggle classes,...)

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container-for-partial")
const partial = "<%= j render 'some_partial' %>"
// Inject HTML to partial
container.innerHTML = partial
```

Comment: Actually I want to rerender the whole view. Not only the partial. In the question it is `show` but without reloading the page. Is it possible?

Comment: If you redender the whole view you might as well just reload the page. But you could just change the JS file and render the whole view in there